# Interesting Awk issue

Tags: bash, awk

This script seems to remove codes that begin with a Letter. When i swapped in P3420 with just 3420 the script worked as intended. No idea what is going on

**Input:**

99443 - PHONE E/M BY PHYS 21-30 MIN,,,,306,,,,

2341        ,GEBHA,BATMAN,01/12/2005,01/10/2005,,230.04,100.00,0.00,

3678        ,DESTEFA,FLASH,01/27/2005,02/02/2005,,230.04,100.00,130.04,

99443 - PHONE E/M BY PHYS 21-30 MIN Total:,,,,306,,,,

P3420 B12 INJ - B12 INJECTION,,,,15,,,,

3437        ,CHAP,GORDO,09/04/2002,09/12/2002,,10.00,10.00,0.00,

3513        ,SARZOS,AHA,10/08/2002,10/01/2002,,10.00,0.00,10.00,

**Script:**

```
while read line
do
    # Debugging:
    if [ -z "$(echo "$line" | awk -F"," '{ print $3 }')" ]
    then
            #echo "$line"
            #if [ echo "$line" | grep '-' ]
            #then
                   var=$(echo "$line" | grep '-' | cut -d" " -f1)
                    echo $var
    fi

    if [ -n "$(echo "$line" | awk -F"," '{ print $3 }')" ]

    then
            echo "$line" | awk -F"," '{ $6='$var';print }' >> testingfile.txt


    fi
 done < $1
```

Output:

2341         GEBHA BATMAN 01/12/2005 01/13/2005 **99443** 230.04 100.00 0.00

3678         DESTEFA FLASH 01/27/2005 02/04/2005 **99443** 230.04 100.00 130.04

3437         CHAP GORDON 09/04/2002 09/13/2002  10.00 10.00 0.00

3513         SARZO AHAAA 10/08/2002 10/08/2002  10.00 0.00 10.00

Comment: The script takes an input file with two types of input lines, let us call them headers and data. There can be more than one sequence of headers followed by data in the file. It wants to output just the data lines, but change them to add in information from the header lines. The program works is the information from the header is numeric but not if it is alphabetical. If it is alphabetical then an empty string is output instead of the expected value.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit removing the input data: I rolled back your edit, since the input data is needed to understand the given script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! Lets try and guess what this script is trying to do.

The outer `while read` loop reads the file sort of one line at a time, joining lines ending with `\`.

The first test sees if the third comma separated field is empty, if so then `var` is set to either empty if there is no `-` character in the line, or the characters up to the first space. var is then printed.

The second test sees if the third comma separated field is not empty. Not clear why this is tested again rather than just using `else`. The 6th comma separated field is set to the value of `$var`, and the line is printed.

So if the line hits the first test and starts with `P3420 B12` then var gets set to `P3420`. The second awk command then looks like

```
awk '-F,' '{$6=P3420;print}'
```

and there is no variable called P3420, so it defaults to the empty string. If the `P` is removed then `$6=3420` assigns an integer and all is fine. So, the root of your problem is a lack of quoting. The command should be

`awk '-F,' '{$6="'$var'";print}'`

Running at least 4 processes per line is pretty expensive! Unix processes are cheap, but not that cheap! The entire file could be processed with a single awk process.

To keep the commas in the output add the assignment to OFS in a BEGIN block

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
           $3!="" { $6=zone; print }
           $3=="" { split($1,a,/ /) ; zone=a[1] }' $1
```